# Create dependency of my library android

Tags: android, android-library

How can I create compile 'xxx-v1.0.0' for my library that could be used directly in build gradle in android studios

Answer (score 0):

You can use this project as a [reference](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber), download or clone it, run it, you will need to install sdk for android 7 in order to run this project.

Take a look at the gradle file for [timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber/blob/master/timber/build.gradle) and [timber-sample](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber/blob/master/timber-sample/build.gradle)